# Find next matching string from list of strings PHP

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string

I'm trying to make an array of variables in PHP in such a way that the variables are ordered in the array based on the order of text in a string.

For example, if I have the string `$s = "Tuesday, Thursday, Monday, Sunday, Wednesday, Saturday, Friday"`, and I have an array of strings `$strings = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", etc.);`, I want to check through `$s` until I find a part of it that matches one of the strings in `$strings`. Then I'll add a variable that represents data for each day to an array, to an array, `$listofdays`, in the order that the days appear in `$s`.

So afterwards, `$listofdays` would look like `($tues_data, $thurs_data, $mon_data, etc.)` based on the order of `$s`

Is there a simple way of doing this in PHP?

Comment: array of variables ?? Are they already defined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood , you want according to order of your string `$s` to check if the element exists in $strings array,for example if Tuesday exists in `$strings` , then we add $Tue_data to $listofdays .

If thats what you want try this :

```
<?php

$s = "Tuesday, Thursday, Monday, Sunday, Wednesday, Saturday, Friday";

$strings = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",);
$ss=explode(',',str_replace(' ','', $s));

foreach($ss as $day){
    if(in_array($day,$strings)){
       $varName = explode('day',$day);

       //$listofdays[]=${$varName[0].'_data'};//contains values of variables $Tues_data.. 
       $listofdays[]='$'.$varName[0].'_data';//Contains literal string '$Tues_data' etc...
    }
}

print_r($listofdays);
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array ( [0] => $Tues_data [1] => $Mon_data [2] => $Wednes_data )
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to create a single pattern based on those strings with alternation, then to apply this pattern to the source string. For example:

```
function getMatches($source, array $strings) {
  rsort($strings); // the easiest way to prevent Wed|Wednesday collisions
  /* more efficient alternative checks length only:
  usort($strings, function($a, $b) {
    $al = strlen($a);
    $bl = strlen($b);
    if ($al === $bl) {
      return 0;
    }
    return $al < $bl ? 1 : -1;  
  }); */
  $pattern = implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $strings));
  preg_match_all("/$pattern/", $source, $matches);
  return $matches[0];
}

$strings = array('$Mon', '$Tue', '$W', '$Wed', '$Thu', '$Fri');
$source  = '$Tuesday, $Thursday, $Monday, $Sunday, $Wednesday';
$res = getMatches($source, $strings);
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/bCIUIC).

After you got this array, it's quite easy to `array_map` it into whatever set of values you like.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you just want to sort your array before you iterate over it?

```
$order = 'Tuesday, Thursday, Monday, Sunday, Wednesday, Saturday, Friday';
$array = array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday','Thursday', 'Friday');

uasort($array, function($a, $b) use($order){
    $x = strpos($order, $a); 
    $y = strpos($order, $b);
    return $x<$y ? -1 : ($x==$y ? 0 : 1);
});

print_r($array); // foreach($array as $day){ /* etc */ }
```

[<kbd>working example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/ln2m3s) *output:*

```
Array
(
    [1] => Tuesday
    [3] => Thursday
    [0] => Monday
    [2] => Wednesday
    [4] => Friday
)
```